# Enterprise Architect how to exclude elements on report

Tags: report, enterprise-architect, bpmn

I want to generate report for my diagram, I've created a simple template:

[image: template]

I want to have only activity task elements listed in my report table, without events, pools and other fields.
I have tried to set elements as non-printable, I was using "Hide annonymous elements" flag, and changed this field in element details, and also I was using Exclude filters. I don't know what is going on but at the end my generated report contains either all elements or none. Is there any magic flag or something? No matter what I change, at the end it does'nt matter, because report is always the same....

Answer (score 0):

You can set a filter in the properties of your template to include only `Activity` elements

[image]

This definitely works as I use that all the time, so if something goes wrong with this there must be something else playing.